# asp.net placing the appSettings in App.config

Tags: asp.net, windows-services, app-config

I am building a windows service app and received the following error

> An unhandled exception of type 'System.TypeInitializationException' occurred in mscorlib.dll

After several experimentations I found changing my App.config file from this

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
  <configuration>
    <appSettings>
      <add key="BancTecFilePath" value="C:\\FTPFolders\\BancTec\\"/>
    </appSettings>
    <configSections>
      <!-- For more information on Entity Framework configuration, visit http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=237468 -->
      <section name="entityFramework" type="System.Data.Entity.Internal.ConfigFile.EntityFrameworkSection, EntityFramework, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" requirePermission="false" />
    <!-- For more information on Entity Framework configuration, visit http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=237468 --></configSections>
    <startup>
      <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.5" />
    </startup>
    <connectionStrings>
      <add name="SamplesEntities" connectionString="metadata=res://*/Model.SamplesEntities.csdl|res://*/Model.SamplesEntities.ssdl|res://*/Model.SamplesEntities.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;data source=unit6cog10sql01;initial catalog=Samples;integrated security=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;App=EntityFramework&quot;" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
    </connectionStrings>
    <entityFramework>
      <defaultConnectionFactory type="System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.SqlConnectionFactory, EntityFramework" />
      <providers>
        <provider invariantName="System.Data.SqlClient" type="System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.SqlProviderServices, EntityFramework.SqlServer" />
      </providers>
    </entityFramework>
  </configuration>
```

to this (moving `<AppSettings>` to the bottom)

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
  <configuration>
    <configSections>
      <!-- For more information on Entity Framework configuration, visit http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=237468 -->
      <section name="entityFramework" type="System.Data.Entity.Internal.ConfigFile.EntityFrameworkSection, EntityFramework, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" requirePermission="false" />
    <!-- For more information on Entity Framework configuration, visit http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=237468 --></configSections>
    <startup>
      <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.5" />
    </startup>
    <connectionStrings>
      <add name="SamplesEntities" connectionString="metadata=res://*/Model.SamplesEntities.csdl|res://*/Model.SamplesEntities.ssdl|res://*/Model.SamplesEntities.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;data source=unit6cog10sql01;initial catalog=Samples;integrated security=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;App=EntityFramework&quot;" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
    </connectionStrings>
    <entityFramework>
      <defaultConnectionFactory type="System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.SqlConnectionFactory, EntityFramework" />
      <providers>
        <provider invariantName="System.Data.SqlClient" type="System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.SqlProviderServices, EntityFramework.SqlServer" />
      </providers>
    </entityFramework>
    <appSettings>
      <add key="BancTecFilePath" value="C:\\FTPFolders\\BancTec\\"/>
    </appSettings>
  </configuration>
```

worked. I took this a step further and kept moving `<AppSettings>` up and found that the highest I could place it was directly below `<statup>`

I always had assumed that each element in `App.config` was simply a reference that would be called as and it was required.

My question is what is happening in the background to cause this error and why does it where it is located

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK you can place appsettings anywhere under `configuration` node.
The only limitation I can think about elements placement is for `configSections` element. Quoting from https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa903350.aspx:

> If this element is in a configuration file, it must be the first child
>   element of the  element.

So you're not allowed to place your `appsettings` (or any element) on top of `configSections`.